# Can Poisson equation be solved numerically in one shot?

Tags: numerical-methods, heat-equation, finite-differences, poissons-equation

I am trying to solve the 2-D Poisson heat equation, i.e.
$\nabla^2T = C$, with boundary conditions (temperatures) for 3 surfaces, and the north surface is insulated.

So I created an $N \times N$ grid, and I constructed the system of linear equations $Ax=b$ where A (for a $3 \times 3$ grid);

$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&-1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&-1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0&-1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&100&-400&100&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \backslash \ \  b=\begin{bmatrix}0\\
0\\
0\\
T_{north}\\
C\\
T_{east}\\
T_{south}\\
T_{south}\\
T_{south}\\\end{bmatrix}$

(the middle row of $A$ is because of the inverse square of $\Delta_x$, which is $ = 0.1$)

Does this look correct? Can I just solve this and reshape $x$ to $N \times N$, and the values represent the steady state temperatures of each node?

Thanks for any help,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You A should look like the following (divide it by your $(\Delta_x)^2$):

> ```
> -4     1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
>  1    -4     1     0     1     0     0     0     0
>  0     1    -4     0     0     1     0     0     0
>  1     0     0    -4     1     0     1     0     0
>  0     1     0     1    -4     1     0     1     0
>  0     0     1     0     1    -4     0     0     1
>  0     0     0     1     0     0    -4     1     0
>  0     0     0     0     1     0     1    -4     1
>  0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1    -4
> ```

the above represents $$\frac{u_{i+1,j}-2u_{i,j}+u_{i-1,j}}{(\Delta x)^2} + 
\frac{u_{i,j+1}-2u_{i,j}+u_{i,j-1}}{(\Delta y)^2}$$
with $(\Delta y)^2=(\Delta x)^2=1$

This matrix is too small, but see this row

```
> 0     1     0     1    -4     1     0     1     0
```

the the ones closest to 4 are derivative in one direction, the farther ones are the another direction.

Now for the BCs, at the end point (with index as $n$) you have
$$\frac{u_{n+1,j}-2u_{n,j}+u_{n-1,j}}{(\Delta x)^2} + 
\frac{u_{n,j+1}-2u_{n,j}+u_{n,j-1}}{(\Delta y)^2}=f_{n,j}$$
the node $n+1$ exceed the matrix size, but its value is known from BC, so you can move it to the RHS. Similarly with the other end point with index 1, you will get node $1-1$ which exceed the matrix size - move it to the RHS as well.

Comment: Thanks Michael. This looks like the correct answer, I also saw in some MATLAB examples, but I don't understand this. My intuition is that the [1, 1, -4 , 1, 1] 's should be for the internal nodes. Since the boundaries (and corners) do not have neighbors to approximate the derivative. Also how do I take into account BC's? Do I solve this A, and then replace the boundary values of $x$ with them? It does not sound right to me too. And what about the insulation?

Comment: There is several ways to do it, the simplest is to move the BCs to RHS. See also update in a while.

Comment: Thank you very much! But it's still not clear for me. What do you mean by "move BC values to RHS"? So I keep the relevant row of A (with a `-4`, and (3 `1`'s for a surface. 2 `1`'s for a corner)) , and set RHS equal to $C + T_{boundary}$ ? That's what I'm confused about. Are we solving for $T$, or $\nabla^2 T$?

Comment: You solve for T, since this is your unknown. <\br> Moving to RHS simple example: Consider an equation $u_0-u_1+u_2\dots=f$ where $u=(u_1,u_2,\dots,u_n)$, so $u_0$ exceed the vector, but it is a known (from a BC) value. Therefore the equation becomes $-u_1+u_2 \dots =f-u_0=\tilde f$

Comment: Ok, so for the boundary nodes, I replace the $C$ in RHS with $C - T_{boundary}$.

Comment: probably $C-\alpha T_{boundary}$ for example if $u_0$ is multiplied or divided by something...i.e. the new equation shouldn't change the result.

Comment: I think there is no multiplication, since in the original equation it's coefficient was 1, $\alpha$ should be 1 too. But still the insulation condition remains.. How do I take into account $\frac{\delta T}{\delta y} = 0$ for the north surface?

Comment: for the neumann BC you have (in general) to add equation, but it could be in place. For example: equation you have $\alpha u_0+\beta u_1+...=f$ and the neumann says $u_0-u_1=g$ then your new equation is $(\beta-1)u_1+\dots=f-(\alpha+1) u_0$

Comment: Thanks. I think I got it now. I will try and hopefully solve this :)

Comment: Just to be sure, you meant to divide by $\Delta_x^2$, not $\Delta_x$, right?

Comment: you are welcome :) thanks for your help too, I think I solved it.